# why facebook maximum number of managed accounts showing zero

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have Facebook business account and standard access level. In my FB APP > Settings >  Advanced > Advertising Accounts, when I click on Ads API then it shows me "maximum number of managed accounts = 0". Although I have 5 Ads account in my business manager without payment method added. Please see attached screen shot.

[image]

[image]

Here you will notice that "Add" button is also showing disabled.

As per me,

1. I have not added payment method in ads account that is why these are not showing.
2. In attached screen shot, ad account id from my personal ad account was showing but none of ad account id from business account is showing.

Any suggestion, what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your observation is right. There needs to be a payment method associated with the adaccount for it to be come up as a managed adaccount.